# Office365 API - Azure Application domain wildcard

Tags: azure, office365, office365-apps, office365-restapi

I have question about applications in Microsoft Office365 (Azure). I have created App to synchronize calendar with our web application.

We have multiple installations on custom subdomains such as

```
subdomain.ourdomain.com 

subdomain2.ourdomain.com

subdomain3.ourdoimain.com
...
```

I set login URL in app (insude Azure) to

```
subdomain.ourdomain.com/auth/office/login
```

But when I try to login from another subdomain - It is failed 'cause there is wrong request URL.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem but just found the solution.

You can use a wildcard in the reply url that is specified in your app configuration like this:

```
*.ourdomain.com/auth/office/login
```

This will allow the redirect URL to point to any subdomain.  Just tested it.